# Using mvtnorm package to build my own multinomial probit model

Tags: regression, probability-density, unordered

I am trying to build a multinomial probit model using the `optmix` and `mvtnorm` packages. Am not using the existing libraries for MNP since I will be extending it to multivariate models later.

For simplicity, I am trying to build a model that has three alternatives. say, car, bus and train are the alternatives. Each individual chooses one of these three alternatives.

Following is how I defined the model. I started initially with a constants only model.

```
# defining the utilities of each alternative (assuming only constants), pars[1] and pars[2] are the coefficients to be estimated #
  ucar    <<- 0
  ubus   <<- parm[1]
  utrain   <<- parm[2]

# defining the variance-covariance matrix, initially assuming correlations are zero and variances are of unit magnitude #
  cormat <<- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

# determining the probabilities of choosing car, bus and train #
  pcar    <<- pmvnorm(lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf), upper = c(ucar,-ubus,-utrain), mean = c(0,0,0), sigma = cormat)
  pbus   <<- pmvnorm(lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf), upper = c(-ucar,ubus,-utrain), mean = c(0,0,0), sigma = cormat)
  ptrain   <<- pmvnorm(lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf), upper = c(-ucar,-ubus,utrain), mean = c(0,0,0), sigma = cormat)

# extracting only the probabilities from mvtnorm and finding out the log of probabilities #
  pcar_1  <<- pcar[[1]]
  pbus_1 <<- pbus[[1]]
  ptrain_1 <<- ptrain[[1]]

  lpcar   <<- log(pcar_1)
  lpbus  <<- log(pbus_1)
  lptrain  <<- log(ptrain_1)

# defining the log-likelihood function, where car, bus and train are dummy indicators for chosen alternatives #
  ll  = -1*(car*lpcar + bus*lpbus + train*lptrain)
```

I maximize the above ll using optmix to get the parameters.
The above model works fine. The problem comes when I add an independent variables in the model. I get an error "Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters". What am I doing wrong in the code ?